# Displaying variables in memory declared in previous pages

Tags: php, variables, include

is it possible in php to use var_dump or a similar function to display all the variables that are still in scope? for example, pageA.php includes pageB.php, and I want in the latter to see which variables are available from previous pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 echo '< pre >';
  var_dump ( get_defined_vars() );
 echo '< /pre >';
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `get_defined_vars()`.  You can use it like this:

```
var_dump(get_defined_vars());
```

This will show all defined variables available to scope from which the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

if page A contains `<?php $var = "HELLO"; include("pageb.php");?>` then page b will have full access to the variable as `<?php echo $var;?>`

This obviously changes though if you start defining/declaring classes as if you define a variable within the scope of a class in pagea then pageb will only have access to it if that class is a) already instanced and b) the variable is public and exposed

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to use get_defined_vars(), read the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php